# How to change the field value of a Shapefile using GDAL/OGR?

Tags: gdal, ogr, fields-attributes

I am trying to change the field value of a shapefile. However it doesn't change the value. What's wrong with my code?

```
import ogr

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
fn = 'dist.shp'
dataSource = driver.Open(fn, 0)

layer = dataSource.GetLayer()
feature = layer.GetNextFeature()

dist = 233

while feature:
    feature.SetField("dist", dist)
    layer.SetFeature(feature)
    feature = layer.GetNextFeature()

dataSource.Destroy()
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The second argument in Open specifies if the data can be updated (written to).  Try:

```
dataSource = driver.Open(fn,1)
```

Comment: This solution worked! confirmed from [GDAL-PYTHON API](http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr-pysrc.html#Driver.Open). Default option is 0 i.e FALSE, otherwise 1 for TRUE incase updating is required